# Using pppd with a serial port?

Tags: linux, unix, serial, point-to-point-protocol

I just need to send/receive a messages through a [unix-socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) with PPP. But at first I want to launch the pppd with an usual serial port to make sure I know how it works. As I see, if I bind a pppd to a serial, all the packets that has come there will be unwrapped from PPP/IP/..., and redirected to some port with my application. As I understand this could be only done by creating a new network interface by the pppd. So I am need to give an IP to pppd. After reading a manuals, and [getting some problems](https://github.com/paulusmack/ppp/issues/10) I figure out an options that seems to be right, but I still can't get it working:

```
$ pppd local -detach 10.5.57.198: /dev/ttyS4
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyS4
LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Connection terminated.
Modem hangup
```

Before the title `LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests` appears I have some time, and I launched in this time `ifconfig` -- alas, here is no new network interface appeared.

Also I was seeked for a tutorials, but all that I found is doesn't seem to be useful, mostly because these deprecated: these often mention a configs, or soft, or sites that is not present right now. And partially because these mention many actions which doesn't seem to carry a sense for me.

So, do anybody knows, what is the options I am missing?

Comment: What do you have running on the other end of your serial connection?

Comment: @MichaelHampton nothing yet.

Comment: PPP stands for "point-to-point protocol". You need 2 points.

Comment: Of course! If nothing is there, nothing can respond!

Comment: @MichaelHampton but I am not try yet ping a connection. The problem is that the pppd doesn't even try to create a network interface -- what should I ping?

Comment: You won't have an interface set up until it successfully sets up a connection. Try actually setting up a connection first.

Comment: Your project makes no sense. I can't imagine what you think is supposed to happen with a PPP link that has only one endpoint. You *can* get a computer to talk to itself over PPP by running 2 `pppd` instances on opposite ends of a pseudo-tty; I have no idea if that's anywhere near your goal. What is the problem you're trying to solve, and what made you think PPP should be involved in the solution?

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley well, I could have i.e. some device on the other side that is down. It is not the reason for a pppd to gone down, because one time the device may appear and send the message. The idea is that I will need to accept a messages through an Unix-socket via PPP protocol.

Comment: Also, UNIX-domain sockets and PPP can't possibly interact with each other, so that part of the question also doesn't make sense

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley so I can't somehow hack it? I found right now the `local` option, that is allow to ignore Data Carrier Detect... Probably I just need to turn off all the interaction with pins of pppd, I think pppd have enough an options for it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton well, okay... Suppose that the interface is appears only when the device on the other side sends a message. This is strange, but conceptually okay. But then why the pppd turned off after some time? It is surely needs to be up, awaiting the message.

Comment: It does have a lot of options, but you need a successful negotiation with the peer before you can do anything else. A large lcp-max-configure will make it wait longer for the connection to start.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley but for example the ethernet don't need to establish a connection to be up. Is there a way to force to have such a behavior the pppd?

Comment: PPP isn't ethernet. pppd was designed to be run after the physical link is established. Its primary use was always on dialup lines, where you didn't want an "always present" interface, but a "manually started by the user when he wants to use the Internet" interface. You deviate from that, you have problems.

Comment: actually I just remembered a relevant option: `persist` (and maybe `demand`) which some dialup users did use to keep the interface alive at all times

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley sorry, overlooked your second comment. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PPP in general, and `pppd` specifically, were mostly used for dialup connections, so all of the defaults assume that the `pppd` process will be started as part of a manually-initiated sequence. The preceding step in the sequence is supposed to be establishing a serial connection (i.e. the modem indicates completion of its handshake with the remote modem by saying `CONNECT`)

You want to reverse the order of things, starting `pppd` first and making it wait for the physical connection to appear. The `persist` option does that.

The documentation for `persist` says

> The **maxfail** option still has an effect on persistent connections.

so you might also need `maxfail 0` to override that. Other related options I can see from a quick look at the man page are `demand`, `idle`, and `holdoff`, all of which will help you control how the in, terface behaves when the peer is not present.

And another useful one: the `connect` option, which is used in the dialup case to specify a program that dials the modem, might be useful to you. You could specify a `connect` script that just watches the serial port status and exits when a connection is present.